# java Filter blocking the file request?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

There was a problem with my filter implementation in Tomcat 7. I have the welcome page `index.jsp`. And it was working fine without the filter. But when i add a small filter to it I am getting `404-Not Found` error.
I have a filter class(in /WEB-INF/classes/filt/Background.java) as follows:

```
package filt;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Background implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
try
{
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("Hello Java");
out.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
return filterConfig;
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

public void destroy() {}

}
```

And my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <application>insights</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Backgd</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filt.Background</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Backgd</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Error from log:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter Backgd
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: filt.Background
```

Even now it works well if i remove the filters part in the web.xml. The problem is with the filter.
What causes the error? Any mistake in filter implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter code is strange, it just write hello world to a file and lets request continue it's way.

Loot at catalina.out to see if you have any messages.
Also check your file generated by filter is  written.

Regards

Comment: checked the log it has the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: filt.Background" . But the Background.java is in "WEB-INF/classes.flit" directory. How is this happening?

Comment: It should be in WEB-INF/classes/filt/Background.class

Comment: I have WEB-INF/classes/filt/Background.java .. Wont this be enough?

Comment: Not at all, tomcat needs a compiled class, so you need to compile your .java into a .class and your issue shoud be fixed

Comment: but how to do that. using javac Background.java gives "class Filter not found" .

Comment: compiling it to .class helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how this particularly works with Tomcat 7, but this would not even compile in Google App Engine. The reason is simple, you cannot under any condition write an output file and store to HDD ... the FileWriter  class it not supported by runtime environment, hence the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Have no clue why it lets you compile the first place. The reason is simple, you could read from files, but not write to files, otherwise, you could potentially have an application that interprets and generates another language.

I dont see any other problem with you filter except that ... if you want to test if its working and matching correctly use this instead

```
System.out.println("Hello Java");
```

Otherwise, its your database